# Declaring Virtual Destructor in base class changes what type a pointer points to?

Tags: c++

I ran across the following behavior writing a simple program to learn about virtual destructors. What I wanted to do was print the name of each class and then compare to what type my pointer was pointing to. I put print statements in each destructor so I could see behavior when switching between virtual and non-virtual in the base class.

Code:

```
class TimeKeeper {....} //non-virtual destructor in base class
class AtomicClock : public TimeKeeper {...} 

int main(){
    std::cout << "TimeKeeper Name: " << typeid(TimeKeeper).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "AtomicClock Name: " << typeid(AtomicClock).name() << std::endl;

    TimeKeeper *ptk = new AtomicClock(rand());

    std::cout << "ptk is of type: " << typeid(*ptk).name() << std::endl;

    delete ptk;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
TimeKeeper Name: 10TimeKeeper
AtomicClock Name: 11AtomicClock
ptk is of type: 10TimeKeeper
I am in the Base Class Destructor
```

However, when I change the TimeKeeper base class destructor to be virtual, the output is this:

```
TimeKeeper Name: 10TimeKeeper
AtomicClock Name: 11AtomicClock
ptk is of type: 11AtomicClock
I am in the Derived Class Destructor
I am in the Base Class Destructor
```

I understand why the dervied class destructor is being called, but I do not understand why the ptk type changed.

**My Question is: Why does the type that ptk points to change when I switch to a virtual Destructor in TimeKeeper class? Or is this me not understanding how typeid works/how to use it?**

Comment: Without the virtual destructor (or any virtual function in the base class) `AtomicClock` is not a [polymorphic object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects), and therefore `typeid` will use the static type of `*ptk` which is `TimeKeeper`. See *2.b)* [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as the difference between calling a virtual function or a non-virtual function. You can either use the type of the expression, or you can use the type of the object. In the case of

```
TimeKeeper *ptk = new AtomicClock(rand());
std::cout << "ptk is of type: " << typeid(*ptk).name() << std::endl;
```

the expression `*pkt` has type reference to `TimeKeeper` but the object referred to has type `AtomicClock`. Either type could be printed by `typeid`. What makes the difference is whether `TimeKeeper` is polymorphic or not, that is whether it has any virtual methods (including a virtual destructor). If `TimeKeeper` is polymorphic `typeid` will use the type of the object otherwise the type of the expression.